# How do I add left and right borders?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to have left and right borders for a particular cell. I'm using bootstrap 4 beta. I've tried using:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td scope="col" class="white-text mx-0 border border-white border-bottom-0">Abc</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: But I have included a small snippet where I want help :(

Comment: Does that snippet actually **demostrate** the issue?

Comment: Thanks Manish Patel for the edit. Really new to this community :)

Comment: Which cells do you want to put borders? maybe :nth-child could help you

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-top-0` to your code

```
<td scope="col" class="white-text mx-0 border border-white border-bottom-0 border-top-0">Abc</td>
```

Adding pen of @paulie-D from below comment

[codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zpaxmY](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zpaxmY)

Comment: but this doesn't add borders at either sides, it just removes the top border

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added your pen to my answer :) I hope you won't mind

Comment: @TweaknFreak I have updated the answer. Check out link :)

Comment: Answers are to contain code within the answer and not a third party site which can go dead and make your answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using an outdated version of Bootstrap 4. 
The most recent version of Bootstrap 4 is beta 3.

Secondly, Bootstrap columns (`.col`) are designed to be used within Bootstrap rows (`.row`).

And the rows should it turn go into a div with the `.container` class.

For a table, just add the class `.table` to get the proper spacing.

Add `.table-bordered` for borders on all sides of the table and cells.

Try this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td scope="col" class="white-text mx-0 border border-white border-bottom-0">Abc</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: "beta" is a beta and not the "current version".

Comment: Bootstrap 4 beta 3 is the most recent version of Bootstrap 4.

Comment: beta software is test software. It should only run with the caveat that there may be problems with it during this testing phase and it should "not" be used in production. You should do so at your own risk. Many companies forbid running beta software in production. If you notice the version number, it has not changed for this very reason. The beta version of *any* software is **not** the current release!

Comment: Wrong! The question is tagged with Bootstrap 4 tag. This requires the use of the most recent release of Bootstrap 4 because there are breaking changes compared to previous versions of Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Also, the asker stated that he uses Bootstrap 4 beta while linking to alpha in his example code. High reputation doesn't seem to equate to high intelligence, does it?

Comment: Again, even Bootstrap says their beta release can break software. You should listen to them. It's the very definition of beta software.

Comment: Again, what you are saying is completely IRRELEVANT here because the asker **expressively** stated that he uses Bootstrap 4 beta while linking to alpha in his example code. Being able to read can really help sometimes...

Comment: I'm commenting on *your* incorrect statement, not anything he said.

Comment: My statement is ***100% CORRECT***! Because the asker stated that he IS USING BETA and alerted him that he has ALPHA AND NOT BETA IN HIS CODE.

Comment: Even someone with a reputation as high as yours should, some point, be able to grasp that a beta version is different from alpha...

Comment: You need to learn what beta software is before you carry on a conversation about alpha software.

Comment: You need to learn reading the actual question and compare it to the code inside. The question is about beta version. That cannot be expected to work with the alpha code that's inside the example code.

Comment: Alright. I'm done with you. This is not the place either.